# Use an array of pointers to structs, or just an array of structs?

Tags: c, data-structures, signal-processing

I'm working on a FFT algorithm in C for a microcontroller, and am having trouble deciding on whether to have the real and imaginary parts of the input data stored in just an array of structs, or use pointers to array of structs.  I'm facing the conflicting requirements that that the code has to run in a tiny amount of memory, and yet also be as fast as possible.  I believe the array of pointers to structs will have a somewhat larger memory overhead, but there's a line in my code basically like the following:

```
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < RECORD_SIZE; i++)
{
    uint8_t decimateValue = fft_decimate(i);
    fftData[i]->realPart = fftTempData[decimateValue]->realPart;
    fftData[i]->imPart = fftTempData[decimateValue]->imPart;
}
```

I'm thinking that if I use an array of pointers to structs as in the above example that the compiled code will be faster as it is just reshuffling the pointers, rather than actually copying all the data between the two data structures as an array-of-structures implementation would.  I'm willing to sacrifice some extra memory if the above section of code runs as fast as possible.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why don't you just run both versions of the code and see which one is faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you access data through an array of pointers, you have two memory accesses.  This often comes with a pipeline stall, even on microcontrollers (unless it's a really small microcontroller with no pipeline).

Then you have to consider the size of the data.  How big is a pointer?  2 bytes?  4 bytes?  How big are the structs?  4 bytes?  8 bytes?

If the struct is twice as big as a pointer, shuffling the data will be half as expensive with pointers.  However, reading or modifying the data in any other way will be more expensive.  So it depends on what your program does.  If you spend a lot of time reading the data and only a little time shuffling it, optimize for reading the data.  Other people have it right -- profile.  Make sure to profile on your microcontroller, not on your workstation.

Comment: The algorithm spends significantly more time reading than shuffling, so it looks like I should go with the straight array implementation.  IIRC, I think the AVR Mega series has a 2 stage pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

If your structs are very small, it will actually be faster to have an array of structs and shuffle them around. If your structs are large, this specific action will be faster if you are only shuffling around pointers.

Wait a minute... on second glance, it appears in your code that you are not shuffling around pointers, but you are accessing fields of the structs that those pointers reference; in effect you are still shuffling the structs themselves, not the pointers. This is going to be slower than moving pointers and also slower than just moving structs since it has to dereference the pointers and then still move the struct anyway.

Comment: I guess I'm curious if the compiler will see that since I'm assigning all the same elements of each structure to each other, all that really needs to be done is change the value of the pointer in fftData[i] to point at whatever fftTempdata[decimateValue] is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The array of pointers will be faster, but there will be an overhead in memory usage. If have memory to use the pointers, use them.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: It depends. Profile.

Cache locality is going to reign here. I expect the structs to be very small (representing complex numbers?). In FFT I'd expect a lot more gain from storing the real and imaginary parts in separate arrays.

You could then split the load between CPU cores.

If it is about larger chunks (say 1024 sample blocks), I strongly suspect that shuffling pointers is way more efficient. It will also allow you to - much more easily - work on the same (readonly) data from several threads. Moving memory around is a certain way to invalidate a lot of iterators, and usually you want tasks (i.e. threads) to work on a subrange of your data, i.e.: all they have is an iterator subrange.

Comment: The question specifically mentions microcontrollers, which usually don't have multiple cores and often don't have caches.

Comment: @Dietrich: good point. Sry I missed that. In that case, I'd avoid any indirection to let the CPU do other things than calculate effective addresses for operands